# Republishing CompressedDepth image to Raw image

Tags: ros, compressed-image-transport, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the following command to republish compressed depth images to raw message topics:

```
rosrun image_transport republish compressedDepth in:=/camera/depth/image_raw/ raw out:=/camera/depth/image_raw
```

However, the above command throws the following error at runtime:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Unknown encoding png
[1]    1475 abort (core dumped)  rosrun image_transport republish compressedDepth  raw
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288515/republishing-compresseddepth-image-to-raw-image/) by [R](https://answers.ros.org/users/34587/r/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, try changing your image_transport from 'raw'

---

Originally posted by [Irikefe](https://answers.ros.org/users/40773/irikefe/) with karma: 36 on 2019-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0